# Perl hash and if-else conditional statement

Tags: perl, hash

Can anyone help please? I can't see where I'm going wrong -

I am trying to create two hashes that contains different keys for the same value from an input file in order to select all the key-value pairs that are greater than or equal to 2 and print it to a separate file.

The input file, where 1st column is ID number, 2nd column is ID name and 3rd column are expression values. 
Input file (input.txt):

```
ENSG00000251791 SCARNA6 2.5
ENSG00000238862 SNORD19B 6.3
ENSG00000238527 SNORD112 -3
```

I want to select the ID numbers and names that have an expression of greater than or equal to 2 and print these out to separate file to look like this:

```
ENSG00000251791 SCARNA6 2.5
ENSG00000238862 SNORD19B 6.3
```

I have simplified a previous script that definitely works (thanks M42) because I'll have very large files and need to save on space.

Here's the code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = 'input.txt';                
open my $input_file_handle, '<', $input or die $!;

while (<$input_file_handle>) {
  chomp($_);
  my @id = split(/\s+/);
  my %id1;
  my %id2;

  my $id1{$id[0]} = $id[1];
  my $id2{$id[0]} = $id[2];
  foreach (keys%id1) {
    print $_,"\t", $id1{$_}, "\t", $id2{$_};
  }
}

foreach (keys%id1) {
  print "$_ ";
  if ($id1{$_} >= 2) {
    print "$id1{$_}";
  } else {
    print "N/A";
  }
}
```

I keep getting requires explicit package name error messages for the @id and %id's. I'm not sure where I am going wrong. If anyone has any suggestions or comments with explanations that would be fabulous.

Thanks
Harriet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the "explicit package" warnings is that you are declaring variables in the wrong scope:

```
while (<$input_file_handle>) {
    ...
    my @id ...
}  # end of block that @id is in -> end of scope

   # @id is out of scope here
```

So if you want your errors to go away, you declare the variables outside the `while` loop. However, the solution you are attempting is not very good. First of all, you do not need to store any values at all, if all you want to do is check if column 3 >= 2. Second of all, you do not need two hashes to store values, you would just use one. Third, there's no point in storing the values of the `split` if you are only interested in re-printing the original line. This is all you really need for that functionality:

```
while (<>) {
    my ($num, $name, $val) = split;
    if ($val >= 2) {
        print;
    }
}
```

All the values here are stored in temporary variables, which go out of scope at the end of each loop iteration.

You would call it like this:

```
perl script.pl input.txt > output.txt
```

It is also a fairly simple one-liner:

```
perl -ane 'if ($F[2] >= 2) { print }' input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = 'input.txt';                
open my $input_file_handle, '<', $input or die $!;

my %hash;
while (<$input_file_handle>) {
  chomp;
  my ($k, @id) = split /\s+/;
  $hash{$k} = \@id;
}

for my $k (sort keys %hash) {
  my $id = $hash{$k};
  if ($id->[1] >=2) {
    print "@$id\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing it to keep both columns id number and name in? I know it over-complicates but I need both IDs. Apart from that, it works great!

Comment: I'm getting more error messages: Use of uninitialized value in numeric ge (>=) at test.pl line 18, <$input_file_handle> line 8. I've tried my'ing @id, $id and commenting out use commands but no output